# How to convert low endian ascii bytes(think so) to text in python?

Tags: python, binary, ascii, string-conversion

Recently, while working on my college project to convert .dat files to excel files,I am not able to convert it no matter what I try.I have very little experience in python and this convertion is crucial or else I have to convert it manually with other softwares.But I have more than 25000 files to convert.Kindly help me in this.
Here is the .dat file's content when readed on binary mode

```
b'\x00\x00\xd0\x05\xdf)\x93EW\x1e\x90\xec\xa8K\xe5@\x00\x00t\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x009116-6631 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00                \x9c#\xe7\x19\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00Default         \xff\xff\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x80\x03\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00All Chan        \x00\x00\x10\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff(\x10\x00\x00\xf0A\xc0\xc0\xc0J\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P1    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T1    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P2    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T2    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P3    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T3    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P4    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T4    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P5    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T5    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P6    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T6    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P7    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T7    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P8    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T8    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P9    \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T9    \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P10   \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T10   \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P11   \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T11   \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P12   \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T12   \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P13   \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T13   \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P14   \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T14   \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P15   \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T15   \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xd7D\xd9\xa1\xdc@\x00\x00\x00\x00P16   \x00\x03kPa   \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00T16   \x02\x02degC  \x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?()    \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff`\x00\x00\x00>=\x9c#\xe7\x19v\x02\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00;9\xd9\xbe\nOy\xbe\x85_\xe5\xbf=Fx?z\x93\x17\xbfK\xda\xb4<t\xac\xb9<\x85}\t\xbf\x1a\xaf\xb7\xbfG\xb3\xd6=c\xc0\x00?\xd1W\x1d\xbf8\xfc\x82>\xce\x00\xf3\xbe\xf6sAAZ\xafRA\x00\xff\xe0\x00\x00\x00@=\x9c#\xe7\x19*\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x030\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x8b\xf1A@\n\xfcA\x80\x8f\xeeA\xc0;\xefA@\xa1\xf2A\xc03\xf1A\x80\xa0\xeeA\xc0\xa4\xefA\x80_\xf3A\xc0\xb8\xfbA\x80Q\xfbA\x80<\xf0A\x80d\xf3A\xc0k\xf1A\x003\xf2A\x80\xf4\xf0A\xfdY\xd9F\x02t\xe0F\xeeO\xe0F\x05\xba\xddF\xf4Q\xe0F\x02\x8e\xdfF\xf5Q\xdaF\xf4=\xdaF\xf1\x15\xd9F\x05\x86\xe0F\x02\x1c\xdfF\x01\x8c\xdcF\xfe\xa9\xdaF\x00.\xe0FMX\xdbFO\xb8\xdaFN\xd9\x87@\x9aI\x8c@\r3\x8c@X\x95\x8a@Q4\x8c@\xd9\xb9\x8b@Jt\x88@\xc9g\x88@\xc6\xae\x87@\xdcT\x8c@\x98r\x8b@\x94\xd8\x89@P\xab\x88@\xd8\x1d\x8c@B\x18\x89@C\xb4\x88@\x00\xff`\x00\x00 \x0c?\x9c#\xe7\x19w\x02\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00^`N\xbf\x0cj\xad\xbe\xe5\x15\xd9\xbf\x9b\xbb_?z\x93\x17\xbf\xc5m\x97\xbdq;\xf2=\xc8\x85\x80\xbe\x13F\xb0\xbf\xa9\xc2\x97>\x08\xe7\x9f>\x1f\x88\xd8\xbe,\x8a\xb3>a\x02\xc2\xbe\xdb\nFA\x9b\xbfUA\x00\xff`\x00\x00@\x86?\x9c#\xe7\x19x\x02\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\xef5\xbf\x1ew\x07\xbf\x89\x82\xc0\xbf\x9b\xbb_?M3\xfe\xbe\x0e\t.\xbeq;\xf2=\x85}\t\xbf\xeas\xa1\xbfXpM>65\x8d\xbd_\xe15\xbf\xd5\xf1\xfc\xbd\xce\x00\xf3\xbe\xdb\nFA\xfa\x16NA\x00\xff\xa0\x00\x00P\x86?\x9c#\xe7\x19\x9e\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x02 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x86C\x00\x00\xfeB\x00\x00\xe8B\x00\x00j\xc3\x00\x00\xf4B\x00\x00\xc0B\x00\x00\xba\xc2\x00\x00\x98A\x00\x00\x94\xc3\x00\x001\xc3\x00\x00\xe6B\x00\x00\xaaB\x00\x00\x88A\x00\x00DB\x00\x00\x10B\x00\x00\x80AO\x81\'=>\xc1\x9e<"\x01\x91<$A\x12\xbd1\x81\x98<\xe0\x01p<\xd1\x81h\xbc|\x01>;r\x019\xbd\xbaA\xdd\xbc \xc1\x8f<\xa9\x81T<T\x01*;\xea\x01\xf5;h\x01\xb4;@\x01 ;\x00\xff`\x00\x00`\xc6?\x9c#\xe7\x19y\x02\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00l\'\r\xbe$,\xde\xbe\xe1\xf2\xfd\xbf=Fx?M\r0\xbf1\xd9\xf1=\x9c\x07[>\xff(\xe2\xbe\xdb\xa1\x92\xbf\xe3\xe7:\xbeW4(\xbe\x1f\x88\xd8\xbeAS\n?a\x02\xc2\xbe\x97\xfbBAZ\xafRA\x00\xff`\x00\x00H\x03@\x9c#\xe7\x19z\x02\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00b~\x1d\xbf\x1ew\x07\xbfN\x1e\x05\xc0=Fx?M3\xfe\xbe/-\x88\xbe\xaah\x95\xbd{g\x1f\xbe0\xea\xcd\xbf\xbe<\x14<T4^>\xd1W\x1d\xbf8\xfc\x82>a\x02\xc2\xbe\xf6sAAZ\xafRA\x00\xff`\x00\x00X#@\x9c#\xe7\x19{\x02\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\xef5\xbf\x0cj\xad\xbe\x85_\xe5\xbfoh\x88?\xe9\x86H\xbfK\xda\xb4<t\xac\xb9<\x8fO:\xbf\x13F\xb0\xbf\xd1\xa5\xb1\xbdc\xc0\x00?[kN\xbf\x12\xe8\xea\xbc\xd4~*\xbf\x97\xfbBA\x9b\xbfUA\x00\xff`\x00\x00pC@\x9c#\xe7\x19|\x02\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xadW\xa8\xbe\nOy\xbe%\xa9\xf1\xbf\x9b\xbb_?\x14@\xcd\xbe\xc5m\x97\xbd\xaah\x95\xbd\x8fO:\xbf\xeas\xa1\xbf\xd1\xa5\xb1\xbdv3\xf9=\x1f\x88\xd8\xbe \x18\xe4>\x9d\xff\x11\xbfR\xec?A\xfa\x16NA\x00\xff\xa0\x00\x00\x80C@\x9c#\xe7\x19\x9f\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x00\x00\x02 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x88C\x00\x00\x02C\x00\x00\xe0B\x00\x00j\xc3\x00\x00\xf6B\x00\x00\xc2B\x00\x00\xbe\xc2\x00\x00\x88A\x00\x00\x94\xc3\x00\x004\xc3\x00\x00\xeaB\x00\x00\xb0B\x00\x00\xb8A\x00\x00@B\x00\x00\x00B\x00\x00\x80AT\x01*=E\x81\xa2<\x18\x01\x8c<$A\x12\xbd4\xc1\x99<\xe5\x81r<\xdb\x81m\xbcT\x01*;r\x019\xbd\xc2\x01\xe1\xbc$A\x92<\xb8\x01\\<\xcc\x01f;\xe0\x01\xf0;@\x01\xa0;@\x01 ;\x00\xff`\x00\x00\x80c@\x9c#\xe7\x19}\x02\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\x01\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00c\xebn\xbe\nOy\xbe\xe1\xf2\xfd\xbf=Fx?nL\x9c\xbe\xc5m\x97\xbdQx\x9e>\xff(\xe2\xbe"\x18\xbf\xbfXpM>\x08\xe7\x9f> \xf5f\xbf\xab\xdb$>\xce\x00\xf3\xbe\xf6sAA:\'QA\x00\x010\x00\xddF\x93Ez5\xf1\xec\xa8K\xe5@\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00End File        '
```

here is the code I used

```
with open('data.dat'.'rb') as d:
    f=d.read()
    g=f.decode('utf-8')
    print(g)
```

I have tried utf-8,utf-16,latin-1,iso-8859-1 and ascii.Please help me

Comment: What is source of your .dat files?

Comment: It is a pressure system software named NUSS.

Comment: This is what I got from software manual       All records in these data files contain variable length binary records, all generated by
NUSS itself. The data streams are not directly
written to these files. Instead, NUSS reads the acquired streams into main memory,
converting any binary (big endian), decimal, or hexadecimal formatted data directly into
its PC-usable binary (little endian) form. It saves the decoded results in special memory
buffers (actually “sparse” 3-dimensional arrays, organized by module, data group, and
channel #).

Comment: How to convert it to excel file if its binary data?